# Lucene query with grouping and proximity

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to create a search query using lucene syntax for Elasticsearch with both grouping and proximity (and wildcard too if this is possible).

The goal is to find `'a' OR 'b' within a certain distance from 'c'`.

So I've tried something like `"('a' OR 'b') c"~2` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Is there a way to do that? And is it possible to have wildcard for a specific word in phrase? Something like `"('a*' OR 'b*') c"~5`